# Error when trying to compile in Linux

Tags: linux, curl, make

I'm trying to compile [tsschecker](https://github.com/tihmstar/tsschecker) from GitHub and am having an issue. I went through and installed all the dependencies then managed to run the `autogen.sh` script without issue.

I'm now trying to run `make` but am getting the error below:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/tss/tsschecker-master/git/tsschecker# make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/tss/tsschecker-master/git/tsschecker'
Making all in tsschecker
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/tss/tsschecker-master/git/tsschecker/tsschecker'
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0  -I../external/jssy/jssy/ -g -O2 -std=c11 -D TSSCHECKER_VERSION_COUNT=\"304\" -D TSSCHECKER_VERSION_SHA=\"b9d193aa6e6d24421094873c830692d02d8b32f5\" -L/usr/local/lib -lplist -L/usr/local/lib -lfragmentzip -lcurl -lzip -lz -lcurl -lcrypto -L/usr/local/lib -lirecovery -lm  -o tsschecker tsschecker-tsschecker.o tsschecker-tss.o tsschecker-download.o tsschecker-main.o -L/usr/local/lib -lplist -L/usr/local/lib -lfragmentzip -lcurl -lzip -lz -lcurl -lcrypto -L/usr/local/lib -lirecovery -lm libjssy.a
libtool:   error: cannot find the library '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.la' or unhandled argument '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.la'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:527: tsschecker] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/tss/tsschecker-master/git/tsschecker/tsschecker'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:410: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/tss/tsschecker-master/git/tsschecker'
make: *** [Makefile:342: all] Error 2
```

I've tried reinstalling curl but that doesn't seem to have helped. The `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory that it's looking for does not exist.

I'm quite new to this side of Linux so I apologise is anything here doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is written in the README.
Anyway, you need of libcurl.la

```
libtool:   error: cannot find the library '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.la' or unhandled argument '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.la'
```

you need libcurl3 (this is dependencies), then you should install it with:

```
$ sudo apt install libcurl3
```

If you have problem with the libcurl version, follow [these instructions](https://dev.to/jake/using-libcurl3-and-libcurl4-on-ubuntu-1804-bionic-184g)
If the make needs other libraries/files you need search it in the ubuntu/debian database in the following way:

```
$ sudo apt install apt-file
$ sudo apt-file update
$ apt-file search my_library_to_search
```

Here apt-file will tell you the package that contain the file you need, from here you need to install the package you need and then continue with make.
Anyway the dependencies are all in the readme:

```
libcurl
libplist
libfragmentzip
openssl or commonCrypto on macOS/OS X;
libirecovery
```

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense when put that way. I'm am however unable to install libcurl3 using apt-get as it is saying it is not available. Would you be able to point me in the direction of an alternative?

Comment: I suggest you to read a bit of documentation on how to use/manage the apt system on ubuntu/debian. Anyway if u don't find the the package u should try "apt search libcurl" to search it. Or "apt-file search file" to fine the exact package u have to install.